# How to render a texture on moving circles with SDL2 and OpenGL in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

This is my current code :

All the include

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "SceneOpenGL.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef WIN32
#include <GL/glew.h>

#else
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL3/gl3.h>

#endif

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Voiding my function

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments);
void DrawEllipse(float cx, float cy, float a, float b, int num_segments);
void Rotation(float a,float b,float r, float g_theta );
```

The main function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
SDL_Window* fenetre(0);
SDL_GLContext contexteOpenGL(0);

SDL_Event evenements;
bool terminer(false);

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "Erreur lors de l'initialisation de la SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);


SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);


fenetre = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL 2.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

if(fenetre == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Erreur lors de la creation de la fenetre : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}

contexteOpenGL = SDL_GL_CreateContext(fenetre);

if(contexteOpenGL == 0)
{
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
    SDL_Quit();

    return -1;
}


#ifdef WIN32

    GLenum initialisationGLEW( glewInit() );

    if(initialisationGLEW != GLEW_OK)
    {

        std::cout << "Erreur d'initialisation de GLEW : " << glewGetErrorString(initialisationGLEW) << std::endl;

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexteOpenGL);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

#endif
```

Main loop with the display of the circle and the ellipse

```
 while(!terminer)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&evenements);

    if(evenements.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
        terminer = true;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

float g_theta = 0.0f;

while (g_theta<360)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
g_theta += 1.0f;
DrawCircle(0, 0, 0.3, 50);
Rotation(0.8,0.65,0.1,g_theta);
Rotation(0.5,0.5,0.2,g_theta);
Rotation(0.1,0.1,0.01,g_theta);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(fenetre);
}
}
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexteOpenGL);
SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}
```

Function creating the circle

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
{
    float theta = 2.0 * M_PI * float(ii) / float(num_segments);

    float x_c = r * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component
    float y_c = r * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2f(x_c + cx, y_c + cy);//output vertex
}
glEnd();
}
```

Function creating the ellipse

```
    void DrawEllipse(float cx, float cy, float a, float b, int num_segments)
{
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
    {
        float theta = 2.0 * M_PI * float(ii) / float(num_segments);

        float x_e = a * cosf(theta);//calculate the x component
        float y_e = b * sinf(theta);//calculate the y component
        glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex2f(x_e + cx, y_e + cy);//output vertex
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Function that links the circle and the ellispe

```
    void Rotation(float a,float b,float r, float g_theta )
{

float x = a * cosf(g_theta * M_PI / 180.0f);
float y = b * sinf(g_theta * M_PI / 180.0f);
float d = sqrtf( x*x + y*y );

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( g_theta, 0, 0, 1 );  // rotation around the z axis
glTranslatef( d, 0, 0 );        // translation by the distance

DrawCircle(0, 0, r, 50);
glPopMatrix();

DrawEllipse(0, 0, a, b, 50);

}
```

Its result is :

compilation's result : the red cricles are actually moving  on their own blue ellispes
[image]

I would like that each circle has its own texture.
I already donwloaded SDL2_image and tried this code :

```
  IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG);
  SDL_Surface * image = IMG_Load("PICT3159.JPG");
  IMG_Quit();
```

But nothing happend.
How can I render textures on this moving circles?

(PS : My final goal is to create a 2D representation of our solar system.)

EDIT :

I know how to display an image.
I do it like this :

```
    SDL_Renderer *pRenderer = 
    SDL_CreateRenderer(fenetre,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED); // Création d'un 
    SDL_Renderer utilisant l'accélération matérielle

    if ( pRenderer )
{
        SDL_Surface* pSprite = SDL_LoadBMP("earth.bmp");
        if ( pSprite )
    {
            SDL_Texture* pTexture = 
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer,pSprite); // Préparation du sprite
        if ( pTexture )
        {
            SDL_Rect dest = { 640/2 - pSprite->w/2,480/2 - pSprite->h/2, pSprite->w, pSprite->h};
            SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer,pTexture,NULL,&dest); // Copie du sprite grâce au SDL_Renderer

            SDL_RenderPresent(pRenderer); // Affichage
           SDL_Delay(3000); /* Attendre trois secondes, que l'utilisateur voit la fenêtre */

          //  SDL_DestroyTexture(pTexture); // Libération de la mémoire associée à la texture
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"Échec de création de la texture (%s)\n",SDL_GetError());
        }

        SDL_FreeSurface(pSprite); // Libération de la ressource occupée par le sprite
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Échec de chargement du sprite (%s)\n",SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer); // Libération de la mémoire du SDL_Renderer
}
else
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Échec de création du renderer (%s)\n",SDL_GetError());
}
```

Perhaps it would be easier to resize the image, cut it into a round shape and rotate it on the ellipse?
(But I do not know how to do it either)

Comment: You have to create [Texture Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_Objects), in whose data store you load the image to. You have to [`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and you have to set the texture coordinate attributes for the vertex coordinates, see [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml). But likely this question is to broad.

Comment: Do you know an "easy" tutorial to follow to do what you say?

Comment: It would be easier to draw quads and put textures with opacity that define a circle to render what you want